# I want to have url to point to certain part of my apps in facebook page

Tags: php, facebook

Just as the title..

I want developing facebook apps at facebook page tab..

Just as a example.. 
If i have a store like this..
http://www.facebook.com/ryanowebdeveloper/app_273887879387238 (just example i found online)

I want to have some url straight point to the certain product...
do you think have any way i can do it...
I mean that if i open the url.. it still open the facebook page tab but it show the product description already and not the main page..

and i try learn bout the app_data & singed_request.. but seriously i still not much understand about it.. I know that how to get the parameter.. but i duno how to link it to the page..

thank you all in advance who help and sorry for my bad english =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the URL to your page tab App a string with information by adding `?app_data=` or `&app_data=`, depending on your current URL, followed by a string like:

```
?app_data=product_id=23923|other_info=heresomechars
```

**Now** the trick is, this query string information will not be available in your app, since Facebook opens your app in an Iframe. For this reason facebook posts your app information in the **signed_request** variable. Read this signed_request and you will find app_data with the string.

Now you have access to the string of information and let your code decide what to do depending on what it finds in the `app_data` string.

In my example I use the `|` as seperation sign between parameters, since it is easy to split the string on this character, after read the name, which is before the `=` and the value which is after the `=`.

Hope it clears the air a bit.

Comment: i get it =).. thank bro.. it help me!!! And May I ask the app_data can accept json also rite??? mean I write json in app_data

Comment: I haven't tested that yet :) but you could try of course! Watch out that the max length of a URL in IE is around 2000 characters :)